# always visible Hamburger and to hide some of the nav items in the hamburger and some should beside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Components of navbar including some links or items, one hamburger, one vertical line, two or three glyphicons.

from these components only some items will be hidden in hamburger and the items will reveal just after clicking the hamburger.

And all of these will collapse in one button while resizing to sm.

Please help me

```
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/Prothom-alo-logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:40px;"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="#">বাংলাদেশ</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">আন্তর্জাতিক</a>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">অর্থনীতি</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">মতামত</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">খেলা</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">বিনোদন</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ছবি</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ইপেপার</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">উত্তর আমেরিকা</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        <a href="#">সব</a>
            </button>
        </div>
        <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ছবি</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ইপেপার</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">উত্তর আমেরিকা</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ছবি</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ইপেপার</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">উত্তর আমেরিকা</a>
            </li>
        <div class="vl"></div>
        <a class ="english" href="#">English</a>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

links which are written after button, will be hidden in that button.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: hamburger is fully functional but the links and the icons aren't collapsing into hamburger.

Comment: Can you provide a properly structured Navbar.. using nav-link and navbar, etc..?